# Find the order of convergence of the sequence $\left\{\frac{5}{6^{\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^n}} \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, algorithms

Find the order of convergence of the sequence $\left\{\frac{5}{6^{\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^n}} \right\}$

**My attempt:-**

**Definition of Order of convergence**
[image]

We know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left\{\frac{5}{6^{\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^n}} \right\}=0$
Consider
$$\frac{|p_{n+1}-p|}{|p_n-p|^{\alpha}}=\frac{\frac{5}{6^{(\frac{7}{3})^{n+1}}}}{(\frac{5}{6^{(\frac{7}{3})^n}})^{\alpha}}=5^{1-\alpha}\frac{6^{\alpha(\frac{7}{3})^{n}}}{6^{(\frac{7}{3})^{n+1}}}=5^{1-\alpha}6^{\alpha(\frac{7}{3})^{n}-(\frac{7}{3})^{n+1}}=5^{1-\alpha}6^{(\frac{7}{3})^{n}(\alpha-(\frac{7}{3}))}$$

Here $\alpha=7/3$. right?

Comment: Please, avoid the use of images. This one in particular is not very readable.

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: I see no errors. You might want to look at using `\left` and `\right` in MathJax: e.g. $\left\{\frac{5}{6^{\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^n}} \right\}$. This is a bit unbalanced because $5$ is so much smaller than $6^{\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)^n}$. I would have used $5\cdot6^{-(7/3)^n}$ to make a better formatted title.